# KuCoin API - TypeError: request.charAt is not a function

Tags: node.js, kucoin

I'm trying to make a request to the KuCoin API to query the balance. I'm using the [NodeJS API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kucoin-node-api) found here but I keep getting the error whenever I execute the code.

And here's the code snippet

```
            data().then(api => {

            const apiKey = api.api_key;
            const apiSecretKey = api.api_secret;
            const contactId = api.contact_id;
            const exchange = api.exchange;
            const passphrase = 'Passphrase';

            /** Init Configure */
            const config =
            {
                key: apiKey, // KC-API-KEY
                secret: apiSecretKey, // API-Secret
                passphrase: passphrase, // KC-API-PASSPHRASE
                environment: "live"
            }

            API.init(require(config));

            if (apiKey && exchange === "KuCoin-Futures") {

                console.log("KuCoin Balance")


                async function getBalance() {

                    try {
                        let r = await API.getAccountOverview()
                        console.log(r.data)
                      } catch(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                      } 

                }

                return getBalance()

            }
        });
```

I the console log I get the following error

```
TypeError: request.charAt is not a function
at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:617:15)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this??

Comment: Are you sure you're providing correct values to your `config` object? Can you see your `console.log()` line in the output? It would be really great to provide a bit more code if possible, like what is this `data()` function, what is this `API` var exactly (`API.init(require(config));` doesn't really make sense I'd say), etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things which look weird in the code snippet you provided, but the sample code from the [`kucoin-node-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kucoin-node-api) library you linked should work perfectly fine. In case you are using that one, try this snippet which should show your account info:

```
const api = require('kucoin-node-api');

const config = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_KEY',
  secretKey: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_SECRET',
  passphrase: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_PASSPHRASE',
  environment: 'live'
};

api.init(config);

api.getAccounts().then((r) => {
  console.log(r.data);
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

In case you're using a different library, [`kucoin-node-sdk`](https://github.com/Kucoin/kucoin-node-sdk) maybe (judging by your code snippet), then try to configure it correctly:

**config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: 'https://api.kucoin.com',
  apiAuth: {
    key: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_KEY',
    secret: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_SECRET',
    passphrase: 'YOUR_KUCOIN_API_PASSPHRASE'
  },
  authVersion: 2
}
```

and your **main.js** (or whatever the name is):

```
const API = require('kucoin-node-sdk');

API.init(require('./config'));

const main = async () => {
  const getTimestampRl = await API.rest.Others.getTimestamp();
  console.log(getTimestampRl.data);
};

main();
```

The code above will show you KuCoin server timestamp only, but should be enough to keep going.

Good luck with trading!